# How to Get Image from other View controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

i have 2 views. A button and an UIimageView in view 1.  In view 2 i have table view with a list of categories and i have set up images for every category using:

```
cell.imageView.image
```

now if i select a row, i should see an enlarged image of that row in view 1.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use delegate methods. Once a row is selected in second view, pass the UIImage object or image name and set it to the imageview in first view.

For more info on delegate methods, pl. see the following links.

[The Basics of Protocols and Delegates](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

[Using Protocols and Delegates to pass data between views](http://www.iphonesampleapps.com/2010/09/using-protocols-and-delegates-to-pass-data-between-views/)

Comment: i used protocols ...it worked for strings but its not working for images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object in Application Delegate:

```
UIImage* currentImage;
```

Now propertise and synthesize the object.

Now when you are in the View2 and the cell is selected, assign the UIImage into the appDelegate's object:

```
appDelegate.currentImage = img;      // Hope you have an array which contains the images 
                                     // which are displayed in the UITableViewCell
```

Then when View2 gets dismissed, call a notification to View1 and in that notification method, assign the image to the UIImageView object of View1:

```
imageview.image = appDelegate.currentImage;
```